# Saving the model architecture with activation functions in PyTorch

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I use PyTorch for training neural networks. While saving the model, the weights of the network are saved, while the activation functions are not captured. Now, I reload the model from the saved weights with the activation functions changed, the model load still does not throw error. Further, the network outputs incorrect values (obviously). Is there a way to save the structure of the neural network along with the weights? An MWE is presented below.

```
import torch
from torch import nn

class Test(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Test, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(10, 25)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(25, 10)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.tanh = nn.Tanh()
    def forward(self, inputs):
        return self.tanh(self.fc2(self.relu(self.fc1(inputs))))
```

To save

```
test = Test().float()
torch.save(test.state_dict(), "test.pt")
```

To load

```
import torch
from torch import nn

class Test1(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Test, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(10, 25)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(25, 10)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.tanh = nn.Tanh()
    def forward(self, inputs):
        return self.relu(self.fc2(self.tanh(self.fc1(inputs))))

test1 = Test1().float()
test1.load_state_dict(torch.load("test.pt"))  # Loads without error. However the activation functions, tanh and relu are interchanged, and the network outputs incorrect values.
```

Is there a way to also capture the activation functions, while saving? Thanks.

Comment: If the goal is to save the model for inference purpose only, you can use [pytorch's jit extension](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.jit.save.html#:~:text=torch.-,jit.,division%20behavior%20will%20be%20preserved.) which saves the model. You won't need the model definition to access your model, as everything will be serialised in your weight file, so your activation functions will be saved as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well to my understanding you have to load the state_dict directly into the same class from which it was saved. Just like loading pickled objects. Right now you have 2 different objects which are Test1 and Test2.

There might be some pythonic way of saving also an object architecture and its properties into one file, but I can imagine it would be quite a hustle to do so which would have to be included in many additional functions, etc.